# Selenium Web Driver _ How to Identify web elements in canvas map

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, phpunit

I have a map as canvas :

```
<canvas class="ol-unselectable" width="1002" height="722" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
```

and I need to locate web elements inside this canvas, in order to apply lot of actions : `get adress, zoom, dézoom map ,...`
But, unfortunately when I use inspect element on chrome browser it didn't detect any web element inside canvas.
I'm using Selenium WebDriver with PHP language
Any suggestions please??

Comment: <canvas class="ol-unselectable" width="1002" height="722" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas> : this is my canvas

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
//*[@class='ol-unselectable']
```

or

```
//*[@class='ol-unselectable']/*
```

or

```
//*[name() = 'canvas' and @class='ol-unselectable']
```

Comment: cruisepandey  Yes i did, but it doesn't working

Comment: It does not give me any error but the click on specific web element inside canvas is not working at all

Comment: cruisepandey any idea to get this issue work??

Comment: @HERROUHajar : Is page URL public ? if yes please share, if no, You need to save the source code into a text file, then upload that text file using file sharing website (free of course). they will give you a sharable link. That link you can give me.